# Issue while creating a timetable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, timetable

I have been trying to create a timetable using SQL Server and I have come up with the following query.

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempConsultantSchedule
FROM SmConsultantSchedule
WHERE ConsultantId = 32
    AND StartDate >= '2022-11-14 00:00:00' AND EndDate <= '2022-11-18 00:00:00'



    SELECT '08:00' AS Slot,
        A.StuName AS Mon,
        B.StuName AS Tue,
        C.StuName AS Wed,
        D.StuName AS Thur,
        E.StuName AS Fri
    FROM (  SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
            FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
            INNER JOIN StuStudent
                ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
            WHERE StartTime >= '08:00:00' AND EndTime <= '08:30:00'     
                AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Monday'
            GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) A
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '08:00:00' AND EndTime <= '08:30:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Tuesday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) B
    ON A.StudentId =  B.StudentId
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '08:00:00' AND EndTime <= '08:30:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Wednesday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) C
    ON B.StudentId =  C.StudentId
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '08:00:00' AND EndTime <= '08:30:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Thursday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) D
    ON C.StudentId = D.StudentId
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '08:00:00' AND EndTime <= '08:30:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Friday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) E
    ON D.StudentId = E.StudentId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT '08:30' AS Slot,
        A.StuName AS Mon,
        B.StuName AS Tue,
        C.StuName AS Wed,
        D.StuName AS Thu,
        E.StuName AS Fri
    FROM (  SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
            FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
            INNER JOIN StuStudent
                ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
            WHERE StartTime >= '08:30:00' AND EndTime <= '09:00:00'     
                AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Monday'
            GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) A
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '08:30:00' AND EndTime <= '09:00:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Tuesday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) B
    ON A.StudentId =  B.StudentId
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '08:30:00' AND EndTime <= '09:00:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Wednesday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) C
    ON B.StudentId =  C.StudentId
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '08:30:00' AND EndTime <= '09:00:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Thursday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) D
    ON C.StudentId = D.StudentId
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '08:30:00' AND EndTime <= '09:00:00'         
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Friday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) E
    ON D.StudentId = E.StudentId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT '09:00' AS Slot,
        ISNULL(A.StuName, '') AS Mon,
        ISNULL(B.StuName, '') AS Tue,
        ISNULL(C.StuName, '') AS Wed,
        ISNULL(D.StuName, '') AS Thu,
        ISNULL(E.StuName, '') AS Fri
    FROM (  SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
            FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
            INNER JOIN StuStudent
                ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
            WHERE StartTime >= '09:00:00' AND EndTime <= '09:30:00'     
                AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Monday'
            GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) A
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '09:00:00' AND EndTime <= '09:30:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Tuesday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) B
    ON A.StudentId =  B.StudentId
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '09:00:00' AND EndTime <= '09:30:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Wednesday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) C
    ON B.StudentId =  C.StudentId
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '09:00:00' AND EndTime <= '09:30:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Thursday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) D
    ON C.StudentId = D.StudentId
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT StuStudent.FirstName + ' ' + StuStudent.LastName AS StuName,
                    #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
                FROM #TempConsultantSchedule
                INNER JOIN StuStudent
                    ON #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId = StuStudent.Id
                WHERE StartTime >= '09:00:00' AND EndTime <= '09:30:00'     
                    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate) = 'Friday'
                GROUP BY StuStudent.FirstName, StuStudent.LastName, #TempConsultantSchedule.StudentId
        ) E
    ON D.StudentId = E.StudentId

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempConsultantSchedule', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempConsultantSchedule
```

The output of the above query returns in the following format.

[image]

The problem I'm facing here is, when there are data available for 08:00 and 08:30 slots the respective time slot is appearing. But, when there are no data available for 09:00 slot, the time slot is not appearing. Kindly see the below image on how I expect it to return the output

[image]

Appreciate if someone could help on how I can make amendments to the above query to get the output as expected.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You're asking a bit much to expect anyone to wade through that massive query and work out how to tweak it for you. Its best to create a [mre] with emphasis on minimal, and including sample data and desired results.

Comment: Theres got to be a cleaner way than a separate query per time slot, but I dont have the time now to wade through it to come up with something

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to simplify your query is to use recursion to generate a reference time table.

After that, you can Pivot your data to create your desired resultSet.

I don't have your table schema or data but a query would be like this :

```
WITH Slots AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,8,'1900-01-01') AS StartDate,DATEADD(MINUTE,30, DATEADD(HOUR,8,'1900-01-01')) AS EndDate
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,30,StartDate), DATEADD(MINUTE,30,EndDate)
    FROM Slots
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,EndDate) < 18
), [Days] AS
(
    SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'1900-01-01') AS [DAYNAME],CAST('1900-01-01' AS date) [DAY]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(DAY,1,[DAY])),DATEADD(DAY,1,[DAY])
    FROM [Days]
    WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[DAY]) < 6
)
SELECT FORMAT(StartDate,'HH:mm') AS Slot,
  [Monday], 
  [Tuesday], 
  [Wednesday], 
  [Thursday], 
  [Friday]
FROM  
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Slots s
    CROSS JOIN [Days] d
    LEFT JOIN SmConsultantSchedule sc ON sc.StartTime >= s.StartDate AND sc.EndTime <= EndDate AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, sc.StartDate) = d.DAYNAME     
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  MAX(sc.StuName)  
  FOR [DAYNAME] IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday])  
) AS PivotTable;
```